# Global UIView touch notifications

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, touch, nsnotifications

I am looking for a way to detect if the UIWindow is touched at all, anywhere, in any view. Then I would like to dispatch a notification that a controller will respond to.

I am using this to make a time out (i.e. logout after inactivity)

Is there a notification I can subscribe to? this would be my preferred interaction. I don't want to have to implement my logic in every single view so categories could also work.

Perhaps there is an API that I am missing.

Comment: Add an overlay view above the key window that intercepts and forwards touch events while sending a notification?

Answer (score 0):

You could always subclass `UIWindow` and override the `sendEvent:` method

```
- (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
{
  [super sendEvent:event];

  if (UIEventTypeTouches == event.type) {
    NSLog(@"Touched");
  }
}
```